# ng-repeat over $http request in Angular

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I made `$http` request in Angular to retrieve some data.

```
$scope.method='GET';
      $scope.url='/files/file.js';
      $scope.fetch=function(){
          $http({
              method:$scope.method,
              url:'files',
              headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

          })
              .success(function(data,status){
                  $scope.status=status;
                  $scope.data=data;
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log(status);
              })
              .error(function(data,status){
                  $scope.data=data||"Request failed";
                  $scope.status=status;
              })
      };
```

It all works fine and in the view I can present the data like this.

```
<div clasS="row" >
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <h2 id="price">€ {{data[0].price.EUR}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then only this data point is presented. However, I want to use an `ng-repeat` now to instead of presenting the prices  only from `data[0]` I want to use all from  `data[i]`. Using

```
<div clasS="row" ng-repeat="i in data">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <h2 id="price">€ {{data[i].price.EUR}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

does not provide the results and does not even do any ng-repeat. I loops through but I does not show the data itself. What do I do wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data` is array of items, `i` variable will actually be the item instance. So just write it as `ng-repeat="item in data"`, with `{{item.price.EUR}}` inside.